# Why am I getting 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error?

Tags: javascript, express

Beginner here, and I dont understand why I am getting max call stack error:

```
app.post('/farms/:id/products', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const farm = await Farm.findById(id);
    const { name, price, category } = req.body;
    const newProduct = new Product({ name, price, category });
    newProduct.farm = farm;
    farm.products.push(newProduct);

    res.send(farm)
})
```

I noticed if I swap to this, I no longer get the error. However, I don't understand why this would work.

```
farm.products.push(newProduct);
newProduct.farm = farm;
```

Here is how I defined the Product schema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        enum: ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'dairy']
    },
    farm: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Farm'
    }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Here is how I defined the Farm schema:

```
const farmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Farm must have a name!']
    },
    city: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, 'Email is required!']
    },
    products: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }]
})

const Farm = mongoose.model('Farm', farmSchema);
```

Comment: If you check the stack trace when the error happens, you should be able to see where it's getting into a recursion loop.

Comment: Does the `Product` class have a setter for the `farm` property? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: You have created a circular referencing structure, not something that will serialise..  eg. `var a = {hello: 'hello'}; a.a = a; JSON.stringify(a)` would fail

Comment: @Keith Why would reordering the push and assignment fix that?

Comment: @Keith I think that should raise a different error about cyclic objects.

Comment: I am not believing that ONLY changing the order of those two lines makes any difference unless there's something non-standard about `farm.products.push` or `newProduct.farm`.  If those are regular properties with no setters on them and if `.push()` is just the regular array method, then the ordering here will not matter at all.  So, for us to help further, we need to know more about those two properties.  As it stands now, this question either contains a false observation or doesn't contain enough information about the properties in question for us to help you explain it.

Comment: FYI, a regular circular reference in nodejs does not blow up the stack like you report when it is serialized to JSON.  Instead, it detects the circularity and throws an exception.  So, there's something going on here more than just the circular reference.  But, you do need to remove the circular reference before you can send the data in the response anyway since JSON by itself does not handle circular references.

Comment: Thank you all for comments. I have provided some info on how I created the schemas. Please let me know if there is more info I can provide.

Comment: Out of curiosity does  `app.get('json replacer');`  return null?